# AngularJS GET Cross Domain with Basic Authentication

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to interrogate a rest service.  If I use CURL I can get the data back without issue.

```
    curl -k -X GET -H "Accept: application/json" -u username:password "https://example.com/v1/apps"
```

However, I've tried several methods for pulling data back using Angular's $http and $resource services and nothing seems to work.

Does anyone have a good example of how to do this with Angular 1.4.6?

It's both a Cross-Domain and Basic Authentication call.

There are so many "like" examples out there, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: This is more likely to be an issue with your server and not related to angular at all. When dealing with CORS, don't forget about preflights.

Comment: CORS questions get asked numerous times a day...not a hard topic to research

Comment: I've spent the better half of the past two days researching an answer to this trying each example that I get.  "not a hard topic to research", true.  However, I'll challenge you to give me an example that works.

Comment: @ScottG that's an unrealistic request. An example that works would require both a client and a webserver. The fact is the client doesn't have to change anything to send a CORS request properly. It's the server that has to deal with it, and the changes you need to make server-side will vary by language and your specific setup and needs. Not all servers that support CORS need preflight requests, not all can use * for the allow origin header. it all depends.

Comment: There's even a website dedicated to CORS and the MDN docs explain it extremely well. Not to mention 100's of posts here for whatever server config you are using

Comment: I walked away and realized, yes, this is a bad question.  My apologies. Let me rephrase, what's the difference between a $http call and a call made by curl?  If I'm passing in the same header, credentials, etc.  and looking for the same content, shouldn't they both work equal?  Does curl ignore something that $http catches?  - Thanks again everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will save someone else some frustration.  A few things were causing the issue.

- The certificate on the target site was invalid.  They were using a self-signed cert with example.com as the domain.
- The call I was using had a capital 'GET' in it, it should be all lower-case.

To solve issue 1, I had to add the server's IP to my hosts with an alias example.com.  It's a major hack, but it was necessary to get around the invalid domain issue. I'm working with the server's owners to have a correct cert put in place.

For the call itself, here an example that works.  I'm using another service for the auth header.  It just base64s the username and password. Replace AuthorizationService.getCredentials() with your favorite base64(username:password) tool. There are several of them out there.

```
    .factory( 
        'ApplicationDetailService',
        [
            '$resource', 'AuthorizationService',
            function($resource, AuthorizationService) {                    
                return $resource('https://example.com/v1/apps/:id', { id: '@id' },
                    { 
                        'get' : {
                            headers: {
                                Authorization: AuthorizationService.getCredentials()
                            }
                        }                            
                    }
                );
            }
        ]
    )
```

Finally, because the target server wasn't passing back the Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * header in its response.  All of the modern browsers to flat out reject the AJAX return.

I was under the assumption that it was an Angular thing, I was wrong.  There's a plug-in for Chrome called Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *, I tried that, it failed because CORS needs your domain in the header.

I found a flag for chrome *--disable-web-security* that tells Chrome to ignore all security.  **FAIR WARNING**: This makes your session very insecure. Only do this for a test environment.  Just modify your shortcut to pass the flag in as a parameter to chrome.exe.

With all of that, I was able to get past my issue and continue developing until the server team fixes things on their end.

Best of luck!

Comment: installing that plugin for Chrome to change your Origin, or using `--disable-web-security` both are ***terrible*** options.  The moment you resort to these options, you are essentially dooming your application to have undetected security flaws.

Comment: @Claies I completely agree with you.  Don't get me wrong.  This is just a TEMPORARY solution to get around an issue.  I don't own the environment that I have to talk to, but am working with the owners to get their issues resolved.  Fortunately, both solutions only affect my environment, they don't impact the overall project.  i.e. I'm not hacking my Angular project.